# Finding parameters of `__init__()` or parameters needed to construct an object in python

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have scenario where I am passing a file name and checking if it has argument `start` as constructor if it has then I have to create instance of that class.

Consider the example where I have a file named `test.py` which have three class namely `A,B,C` now only class `A` has `start` parameter others have other different parameter or extra parameter.

```
#test.py
class A:
    def __init__(self, start=""):
        pass

class B:
    def __init__(self, randomKeyword, start=""):
        pass

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Now I want to write a script which takes `test.py` as an argument and create instance of `A`. Till now my progress is

```
detail = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('test.py', '/path/to/test.py')
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(detail)
spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
```

Bacially I need to write a program which finds init argument of all class in file and create an instance of file with `start` as init argument.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a sensible approach to anything, really…?! You don't know what the file contains really, and you don't really know what you're instantiating, you're  just instantiating it because it happens to have a parameter with a certain name…?!

Comment: @deceze It's a sensible approach to do a Python exercise :)

Comment: @BartoszKP: No. No it's not.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes. Yes it is.

Comment: @deceze It makes sense for me cause as my application is taking python file path as input which will be created by some other user. My application need to run that as server.

Comment: So, can you update your question so that I can copy and paste your 'progress' and try it for myself?

Comment: That's kinda what I'm saying. You're executing some unknown user code merely on the basis of it having a parameter named "`start`". What if it has many different classes in that file that all happen to accept "`start`", but you're not supposed to use them? You're basically defining an "interface" there, saying "name the parameter of a class I'm supposed to run '`start`'". In return that means that name can't be used for anything else inside that file, which is a weird restriction.

Comment: @deceze This make sense. What do you suggest then. I mean I want user to give a python executable on which I can get my server running. For that we need to have the certain restrictions. We can use abstract class but that will show some of the details that we don't wanna show to users.

Comment: You'd usually have a method/function/class of a specific name like `main` and/or the user passes that name to your program. E.g. in the notation `/path/to/test.py:MyClass.start` or something like that.

Comment: @quamrana I was able to do it using the signature of the init/constructor. Although it's not the best approach. I have posted it as an answer. You can check this out and please post your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @deceze it's not a good idea to instantiate a class on the basis of it's init parameter as we're not sure what is there. But it's possible to do it. So I am posting this answer just so that you know how it can be done.

```
#test.py
class A:
    def __init__(self, start=""):
        pass

class B:
    def __init__(self, randomKeyword, start=""):
        pass

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

One of the possibility is

```
#init.py
import importlib.util
from inspect import getmembers, isclass, signature

detail = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('test.py', '/path/to/test.py')
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(detail)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

for name, data in getmembers(mod, isclass):
    cls = getattr(mod, name)
    parameter = signature(cls.__init__).parameters.keys()
    # parameter start
    if len(parameter) == 2 and 'start' in parameter:
        object = cls(start="Whatever you want")
```

Ofcourse it's not the best approach so more answer are welcome and if you are in this scenario consider @deceze comment and define a builder.